# How to ensure atomic read and update operation on mongodb using spring/java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an spring boot application reading from a database table for jobs to process, and I may have multiple instances of this application running on different servers as each job is independent. Once a job is picked up for processing, its status will be update to "running". What I want to make sure is the retrieval of to be processed jobs from each instance to be atomic, how can I achieve this for mongodb using spring/java ?